# How to measure Phonegap UI performance?

Tags: android, performance, cordova

I want to make performance improvements to my Phonegap application, currently targeting Android, but I want to base my actions on some measureable evidence.

Are there any tools I can use to measure the performance of Phonegap UI (time from clicking to finishing the action) on device? And mainly to measure the improvement of these times after I do some performance tuning?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Traceview - it's an excellent tool:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using this

and i strongly recommend it

https://github.com/GameMaker/PhoneGap-Performance-Test--PGPT-

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is GC based language. It means, it has unpredictable GC time which makes main thread stops. This makes UI struggles. On native implementation, you have control to use GC or not.

This wouldn't be a problem on Android. Android always had those struggling because of GC on Java. Considering this fact, most of Android users doesn't care about UX a lot. But on iOS, your HTML5 based app never be better experience than competitor's native app.

There are many workarounds for this GC time issue. Such as incremental-GC, realtime-GC and so on. But actually, there's no real solution. Because the primitive problem is you don't have control.

Regards
Rajeev